# How to return a value (access token) inside a function without promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, spotify

```
const callback = (req, res) => {

  // your application requests refresh and access tokens
  // after checking the state parameter

  if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
   ...
  } else {
    res.clearCookie(stateKey);
    var authOptions = {...};

//rq = require-promise
    rq.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        var access_token = body.access_token,
            refresh_token = body.refresh_token;

        // we can also pass the token to the browser to make requests from there
        res.redirect('/#' +
          querystring.stringify({
            access_token: access_token,
            refresh_token: refresh_token
          }));
      } 
    });
  }
};
```

I have this function that I exported as a `module` so I can use in the main `app.js` as a `middleware` function when, after login, spotify redirects to the /callback.

Since I can't make it as a promise and after it retrieve the value with .then, I was wondering how could I get the `access_token` that will be generated after login in another `module`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can share value between middleware and define it in req. For simpler explain, this is a example :

```
// the first middleware : checkAuth.js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const authValidator = async (req,res,next) => {
  // check token as requirement for auth user
  let token = req.headers['authorization']
  try {
    let verifiedUser = await jwt.verify(token, 'yoursecret', (err, decode) => {
      if (err) return res.send(err.message)
      return decode
    })
    // assign verifiedUser to req
    req.userData = verifiedUser
    // passing to next middleware
    next()
  } catch (err) {
    return res.send('no token provided')
  }
}

exports.authValidator = authValidator
```

It's share to another middleware :

```
// second middleware : checkRole.js
const roleUser = async (req,res,next) => {
  try {
    // call the req.UserData and assign other value
    if (req.UserData) req.userRole = 'Administrator'
    // passing to next middleware
    next()
  } catch (err) {
    return res.send('ooppsss')
  }
}

exports.roleUser = roleUser
```

and in this route you can get them all :

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const router = Router()

const authValidator = require('/checkAuth.js')
const roleUser = require('./checkRole.js')

// arrange every middleware right here
router.get('/myRoute', authValidator, roleUser, async (req,res) => {
  try {
    // take all from before
    return res.json({
      ...req.userData,
      role: req.userRole
    })
  } catch (err) {
    return res.send('oopsss')
  }
})
```